# File copy using getRuntime().exec()

Tags: java, file-io, runtime.exec

I am trying to copy a file. Here is the source. Note, `des` is string variable containing the URL.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().
    exec("cmd.exe\t/c\tcopy\t"+source+"\t"+des);
```

Can anyone tell me why it does not work?

Comment: Read the error stream. It'll contain the answer.

Comment: Isn't it just `exec("copy source " + source + " destination " + des);`?

Comment: You are far better off using Apache Commons' file copy http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html

Comment: @RyanAmos - not in Java.

Comment: I don't suppose you have a stream gobbler that we're not seeing?

Comment: @Vishal: I tried your code its working fine for me.Show us the complete code.

Comment: And there it goes the platform independence (just one remark)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use [FileUtils.copyFile()](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile%28java.io.File,%20java.io.File%29) but anyways try this.

```
String[] command = new String[5];
command[0] = "cmd";
command[1] = "/c";
command[2] = "copy";
command[3] = "test.java";
command[4] = "D:";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec (command);
```

Instead of passing your command as a `single string` construct an `array` and than pass it to `exec`.

I tried this

```
String command = "cmd /c copy test.java D:";
```

worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Advice:

1. Use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to construct the `Process`.
2. That automatically takes care of '2' - break the command into parts.
3. Merge the output streams (not entirely necessary, but makes it simpler to ..).
4. Consume (and *display*) the output streams.
5. But in general, read and implement ***all*** the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: @RanRag I don't use the `Process` class much myself (I prefer to keep it 'pure Java'(1)), but have seen enough problems regarding it's use to recognize that a single-line call to create a `Process` generally fails for the reasons outlined in the article.  It is a tricky class to use properly.  1) That reminds me, forgot to up-vote your answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec`, I believe, send the string to the command processor `cmd.exe`.  So this is running `cmd.exe`, running another `cmd.exe` inside it, and passing your arguments.  I don't have a Windows machine to test it on (thank Gods) but I think there are arguments to `cmd.exe` to tell it to run the arguments as a command line.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`FileUtils.copyFile()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)?